# Centering Plotly Graphic Within Bootstrap Card

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, plotly

My code for producing a plotly graphic within a boostrap card is below. I'm wondering the best way to ensure it is centered within the card on any device.

```
         <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="card bg-light text-white">
                    <div class="card-header bg-dark">
                        <center>A Plot</center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body align-items-center" style="height: 20rem;">
                        <div class="chart" id="some_graph">
                            <script>
                                var graphs = {{some_plot | safe}};
                                Plotly.plot('some_graph', graphs, {});
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`card-body` is not displayed as flex box by default. If you want to use `align-items-center` or even `justify-content-center`, you need to enable the flex behaviors first:

```html
<div class="card-body d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    ...
</div>
```

The default direction of `d-flex` is row so if you want the graphic to be:

- horizontally centered - use `justify-content-center`
- vertically centered - use `align-items-center`
- both - use both